# Separate game loops for rendering and updating without built-in timers or separate threads

Tags: java, swing, animation, time, game-loop

I am wondering if there is a way to update two different operations (in this case, updating and rendering) within a single thread / loop.

In my current scenario I have a TPS (ticks per second) that I want to have set to 64, and FPS (frames per second) that I want to be modifiable by the player.
The reason they cannot be in separate threads like I have been doing is because it causes a inconsistent flickering effect because of the timing between rendering and updating.

I am drawing with `BufferStrategy` and `Canvas`

This is what I was doing previously:

```
// The TPS = 64, the FPS = anything
public void init() {
    tick_thread = new Thread(() -> {
        long start, elapsed, wait;
        while(alive) {
             start = System.nanoTime();
             input();
             tick();
             elapsed = System.nanoTime() - start;
             wait = (1000 / TPS) - (elapsed / 1000000);
             try {
                 Thread.sleep(wait <= 0 : 1 ? wait);
             } catch(Exception e) {
                 e.printStackTrace(System.out);
             }
        }
    });
    render_thread = new Thread(() -> {
        long start, elapsed, wait;
        while(alive) {
             start = System.nanoTime();
             render();
             elapsed = System.nanoTime() - start;
             wait = (1000 / FPS) - (elapsed / 1000000);
             try {
                 Thread.sleep(wait <= 0 : 1 ? wait);
             } catch(Exception e) {
                 e.printStackTrace(System.out);
             }
        }
    });
}
```

This works well, but I want to move from one thread to a single thread and still update them at a different rate. Like...

```
public void init() {
    game_thread = new Thread(() -> {
        long start, elapsed, wait, // etc
        while(alive) {
            // Some calculations
            input();   //  RUNS 64 TIMES A SECOND
            tick();    //  RUNS 64 TIMES A SECOND
            render();  //  Runs 30, 60, 120 times a second
            // Some calculations
        }
    });
}
```

If you could help or try helping, it would mean a lot!

Comment: `"The reason they cannot be in separate threads like I have been doing is because it causes a inconsistent flickering effect because of the timing between rendering and updating."` --  makes no sense at all since the problem is not likely in the tool but in your implementation of use of the tool. But if it's a Swing GUI, then use a [Swing Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html)

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels The rendering happens as the game is getting updated, so it the stutter at the beginning: https://gyazo.com/0c58908143d8638772c9e2c60b4eff03

Comment: What is this link? Please avoid links to outside resources and allow your question to be fully answerable based on the code/text that is presented in the question itself. I have to wonder how thread-safe your code is, since some of those methods *may* be called on the event thread.

Comment: Joseph, but the devil's in the details. Again, your code is likely at fault. Please consider posting a valid [mcve] program so we can test it and modify it.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Its just a gif of my issue. It isnt really explainable with words, you have to SEE it

Comment: Using a BufferedStrategy, you should be able to perform the update, wait for as long as you need and the perform the rendering all in a single thread

Comment: *"single thread and still update them at a different rate"* - As the loop is intreating, simply keep track of how long the loop takes to run and calculate the time since each task was last executed